# Delete row from Jtable of parent page from ShadowBox popup

Tags: jquery, shadow, jquery-jtable

I am using shadowbox to open up a popup. From that popup I want to delete a record from the jtable located at the parent page. My code is as follows.

```
$('#rectificationTable', parent.document).jtable('deleteRecord', {
    key: entityId,
    animationsEnabled : true,
    clientOnly : true,
    success : function() {
        window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
    },
    error : function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

While doing so I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on jtable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'deleteRecord'.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Are you calling this method before the document is ready?

Comment: No this method is being called after a button click.